# How can I put images in my html code using freemarker template and hippo cms?

Tags: html, css, content-management-system, freemarker, hippocms

I'm looking for some help. I'm in a project where i need to upload images to a freemarker template(.ftl) which is coded with html. I'm using hippo cms console to create sitemaps, etc. I need to use local images in my project (from the project directory) but the URL they take is from `localhost:8080/site/images`. But I don't know where `localhost:8080/site` is in my project or where it refers.

Here is the code:

So,

```
  <img src='https://99designs-start-attachments.imgix.net/alchemy-pictures/2016%2F02%2F22%2F04%2F07%2F21%2F9757e437-5ec1-4378-804f-ca0f9567c110%2F380048_Widakk.png?auto=format&ch=Width%2CDPR&w=250&h=250' class="agoraIcon"/>
```

here I was using an Internet image and it works correctly, but I need to use the image at my site/freemarker/images/agoraLogo.PNG.

Here is the project structure:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      font-family: Verdana;
    }
    
    .login {
      color: white;
      padding: 1%;
      background-color: #2B516B;
    }
    
    .contButton {
      padding: 0.5%;
      padding-left: 4%;
      padding-right: 4%;
      color: white;
      background-color: black;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: Verdana;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
    
    .agoraIcon {
      height: 50px;
      width: 200px;
    }
    
    .content {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .credentials {
      padding: 0.5%;
      font-family: Verdana;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
    
    #year {
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <img src='https://99designs-start-attachments.imgix.net/alchemy-pictures/2016%2F02%2F22%2F04%2F07%2F21%2F9757e437-5ec1-4378-804f-ca0f9567c110%2F380048_Widakk.png?auto=format&ch=Width%2CDPR&w=250&h=250' class="agoraIcon" />
  <div class="login" id="year">2018</div>

  <div class="content">
    <p><b>Inicia sesión con tu <br>cuenta de concesión</b></p>
    <input type="text" class="credentials" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="password" class="credentials" name="psw" placeholder="Contraseña" />
    <div>
      <a href="http://localhost:8080/site/welcome" type="button">
        <button class="contButton" type="submit"> Continuar </button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Directory to the image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
<img src='https://99designs-start-attachments.imgix.net/alchemy-pictures/2016%2F02%2F22%2F04%2F07%2F21%2F9757e437-5ec1-4378-804f-ca0f9567c110%2F380048_Widakk.png?auto=format&ch=Width%2CDPR&w=250&h=250' class="agoraIcon"/>
```

to :

```
<img src='../images/agoraLogo.PNG' class="agoraIcon"/>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what i tried but the image appears corrupted. Thanks anyway

Comment: did you check the image path?

Comment: yep, I checked. I found other way to do the page. I'm using now the Simple Document Editor from Hippo but I can't put input types. If anyone knows how to do it I'll be grateful. Anyway, I still looking for information.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to have binary links generated. You can use the @hst.link tag to do this.

I think you need:
<@hst.link path="/freemarker/images/agoraLogo.PNG" var="image"/>

The var image will contain the link.

See the documentation for more details:
https://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/links-and-urls/hst-2-urls.html

May I also suggest you work through our tutorials?
https://www.onehippo.org/trails/demo-tutorials-and-download.html